# standalone mode=image with animated pdf

Tags: standalone, animate

I'm using animate to generate animated images, read by acroread. It seems this pdf can't be included in another TeX file without loosing the animation capabilities so I'm using \includestandalone with mode=tex to generate to have the animated image compiled in the main TeX file. This can take a very long time, at each compilation.

In order to save some time when writing/compiling other parts of the file, I'd like to use the mode=image of \includestandalone for most compilations and only swith tho mode=tex for the final one. However only a blank space is produced, even though a regular pdf viewer like evince has no problem displaying the first view of the animation pdf file.

In the following example, I tried both includestandalone[mode=image] and includegraphics with no success. Of cours, includestandalone[mode=tex] works and includegraphics successfully displays a png version of the animated pdf produced by convert.

Main TeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{standalone,animate,tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

  \includestandalone[mode=image,height=.25\textheight]{test-animate}

  \includegraphics[height=.25\textheight]{test-animate.pdf}

  \includegraphics[height=.25\textheight]{test-animate.png}

  \includestandalone[mode=tex,height=.25\textheight]{test-animate}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Animation TeX file (rename to test-animate.tex)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\RequirePackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{animateinline}[poster=first,controls,loop]{1}%
  \multiframe{5}{icount=0+10}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
      \draw (0,0) -- (\icount:4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Here are the corresponding pictures

pdf->png version of the main TeX file [image: 1]

test-animate.png [image: 2]

Comment: It is hard to understand what you're really after. Why don't you just use the `animate` package option "`draft`" to save compile time  while working on the document?

Comment: Try using the package **pdfpages** this can include pdf documents. But it will be a separate page in the document. Is that good enough for you?

Comment: With standalone every page can be a different size.  This might cause problems.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner: That won't do it since the images are small sketchs, which are commented on the main document.

Comment: @JohnKormylo. I usually draw a rectangle larger than the changing part so that each page is the same size.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using package option `draft` of `animate` while working on other parts of the document in order to save compilation time:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[draft]{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{animateinline}[controls,loop]{1}%
  \multiframe{5}{icount=0+10}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
      \draw (-5,-5) rectangle (5,5);
      \draw (0,0) -- (\icount:4);
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't know this option, but it will have the same effect as my failed attempt at including in image mode: displaying a blank rectangle the size of the actual animated picture. However, I would prefer to have an image of the first page, but I can do without.

Comment: @wilk You could also produce a "short" version of the animation. If it has less than, say a thousand frames, `every=1000` will insert only the first frame and drop the others. However, this option is only locally available (not as a package option).