# How to Bashful this find into this LaTeX animate?

Tags: animate, bashful

Unix command to make png series from gif pictures in a directory

```bash
# steeldriver, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/370132/16920
find -L . -name '*.gif' -execdir sh -c 'for f; 
      do convert -coalesce "$f" "${f%.gif}%05d.png"; 
done' sh {} +
```

Pseudocode

1. Pass the info from `${f%.gif}%05d` somehow to LaTeX in one step.

   - `find` max filename series end and apply this to LaTeX file filename and iterate. Pseudocode to find the max series image count

     ```
     \usepackage{bashful} 
     \bash[stdoutFile=gif_series.tex]
     find -L . -name '*.png' -execdir sh -c 'for f; 
           ... TODO LaTeX + find max image count + apply it to LaTeX
     done ' sh {} +
     \END
     ```

Data files

1. Example list of gif filenames

   ```
   /home/masi/Images/cautious2.gif
   /home/masi/Images/cautious.gif
   ```
2. Example lists of png image series where the end number go max to 99

   ```
   /home/masi/Images/cautious200000.png
   /home/masi/Images/cautious200001.png
   ...
   /home/masi/Images/cautious00000.png
   ...
   ```

LaTeX where I want to direct the image series on own pages where the filenames are now form `out000xyzw`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{bashful}
\usepackage{pgffor} % I think needed, but possibly not since Bash

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}

    % TODO apply here Bashful somehow
    % TODO something wrong here because the bash should be inserted here and not to a new file if the main script is compiled
    \bash[stdoutFile=gif_series.tex]

    % AlexG, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373780/13173
        \animategraphics[
          width=\textwidth,
          controls,autoplay,loop
        ]{12}{out000}{00}{16} % TODO here {out000}{00}{16} for dynamics

    \END

    \end{figure}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

### Testing TH.'s code

I had to do `touch test.stdout test.stderr test.stoutwas` for the script. 
Output with `facepalm1.gif` and `facepalm2.gif` which yiels 0 pages with `pdflatex code.tex` and `xelatex code.tex`

```
r-environment-dictionary/translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translato
r-months-dictionary/translator-months-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translato
r-numbers-dictionary/translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict)
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translato
r-theorem-dictionary/translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict)
No file test.nav.
after EOF
(./test.stdout) (./test.aux) )
No pages of output.
Transcript written on test.log.
```

Output with `pdflatex -shell-escape code.tex`: correct!

### Testing cfr second answer

Corrected working code with removal of `./anim` to `./` and changed `sh` to `bash` (cfr)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{bashful,animate,pgffor}
\begin{document}
\bash
find . -name '*.gif' -execdir bash -c 'for i;
  do
   c=$(convert -coalesce -identify "$i" "${i/\.gif/.png}" | wc -l);
   ((c--));
   printf \%b "$(basename ${i/\.gif/})/$c,";
  done' bash {} + | sed 's/,$//'
\END
\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \foreach \i/\j in \bashStdout {\animategraphics[width=.2\linewidth,controls,autoplay,loop]{12}{\i-}{0}{\j} \\ }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Files

```
masi@masi:~/Desktop/test.animate/anim$ ls
horna.gif  horn.gif   test2.log  test2.sh
hornb.gif  test2.aux  test2.out  test2.tex
```

Output after compilation with `pdflatex -shell-escape test2.tex` when `sh` there

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/translator/dicts/translato
r-theorem-dictionary/translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict)
No file test2.nav.

Standard error not empty. Here is how 
file test2.stderr begins: 
>>>>sh: 3: sh: Bad substitution 
>>>> 
but, you really ought to examine this file yourself!
! Your shell script failed....
\checkScriptErrors@BL ...r shell script failed...}
                                                  \BL@verbosetrue \logBL {Sw...
l.11 \END

? 
L11: Switching to verbose mode
L11: Checking whether any listings are required
L11: Nothing has to be listed
L11: Defining macro for the contents of the standard output file
L11: Opened file test2.stdout
L11: Reading contents of test2.stdout
after EOF
L11: bashStdout :=
/0,/0,/0

L11: Closing file test2.stdout
L11: Defining macro for the contents of the standard error file
L11: Opened file test2.stderr
L11: Reading contents of test2.stderr
L11: bashStderr :=
sh: 3: sh: Bad substitution

L11: Closing file test2.stderr
L11: Wrap up done
L11: bashV: Done!

! Package animate Error: None of the files
(animate)                `-0.pdf',
(animate)                `-0.mps',
(animate)                `-0.png',
(animate)                `-0.jpg',
(animate)                `-0.jpeg',
(animate)                `-0.jbig2',
(animate)                `-0.jb2',
(animate)                `-0.jp2',
(animate)                `-0.j2k' or
(animate)                `-0.jpx',
(animate)                could be found.
(animate)                Wrong file type? Mis-spelled file name?.

See the animate package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.15 \end{frame}
```

Output with `sh`: no .gif animations in pdf, no pdf produced in Fig. 1

Fig. 1 cfr code output when `sh` used

[image]

`test2.stderr` content when `sh` used

```
sh: 3: sh: Bad substitution
sh: 4: sh: c--: not found
sh: 5: sh: Bad substitution
sh: 3: sh: Bad substitution
sh: 4: sh: c--: not found
sh: 5: sh: Bad substitution
sh: 3: sh: Bad substitution
sh: 4: sh: c--: not found
sh: 5: sh: Bad substitution
```

**Solution**: change the original `sh` parts to `bash` as proposed by cfr. 
Output `pdflatex -shell-escape test2.tex`: correct!

OS: Debian 8.7
TexLive: 2017

Comment: The stuff i do in the terminal, i do in the terminal. I don't use another tool for a different purpose, whack it until it does the job i could have done five minutes ago. I consider it a waste of time to use tools that aren't meant for the task.

Comment: What are you counting? The only script you show seems to be converting things. And the pseudoscript doesn't seem to be counting anything either.

Comment: Seems it is pretty hard to make a cow fly.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 That would only be a valid reason if you would solve the problems on your own, not outsource them to other people.

Comment: As I say, on your system, you will need to specify `bash` rather than `sh` as `sh` is evidently not `bash`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, I think this is a bad idea. There's no good reason to run `convert` as part of running `pdflatex`. That said, it can be done.

There are four basic steps.

1. Determine which `.gif` files you want to animate.
2. Convert `foo.gif` into `foo-0.png`, `foo-1.png`, ..., `foo-n.png`.
3. Determine *n*.
4. Make the figure.

For step 1, you could use `bashful` to find all of the `.gif` files, or you could do something a little more sane and simply write down which ones you want to convert. I'll show both methods.

For step 2, you absolutely should just run convert yourself, but you wanted to do it with `bashful`, so that's what this answer does.

For step 3, you *could* use `bashful`, and I guess if you did steps 1 or 2 using `bashful`, you might as well; however, there's no need. We can do this easily enough in TeX, so that's what this answer does.

For step 4, you merely need to execute `\animategraphics` with the appropriate arguments.

Here's my code.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{bashful}

\newcount\seriesmax
\newread\seriesfile

% Count how many files are in the series.
\newcommand*\countseries[1]{%
        \seriesmax=0
        \loop
                \openin\seriesfile=#1-\number\seriesmax.png
        \ifeof\seriesfile\else
                \closein\seriesfile
                \advance\seriesmax by1
        \repeat
        \advance\seriesmax by-1
}

% This is just ridiculous. This should not be done from within LaTeX.
\begingroup
\catcode`\^^A=14
\catcode`\%=12
\gdef\explodegif#1{^^A
        \bashIV{convert -coalesce #1.gif '#1-%d.png'}^^A
}
\endgroup

\newcommand*\makegraphic[1]{%
        \countseries{#1}%
        \ifnum\seriesmax<0
                \explodegif{#1}%
                \countseries{#1}%
                \ifnum\seriesmax<0
                        \nosuchseries
                \fi
        \fi
        \begin{figure}%
                \noindent
                \animategraphics[width=\textwidth,controls,autoplay,loop]%
                        {12}{#1-}{0}{\number\seriesmax}%
        \end{figure}%
}

\begin{document}
% Downloaded from https://media.giphy.com/media/3og0INyCmHlNylks9O/giphy-downsized.gif
% and https://media.giphy.com/media/XsUtdIeJ0MWMo/giphy-downsized.gif
% and renamed to facepalm.gif and facepalm2.gif, respectively.

% One option is to specify exactly what you want.
%\makegraphic{facepalm}
%\makegraphic{facepalm2}

% The other option is to have `\bash` find them for you.
\bash
for i in *.gif; do echo "\makegraphic{$(basename $i .gif)}"; done
\END
\input\csname BL@stdoutFile\endcsname

\end{document}
```

Here're the images I'm going to work with.
[image: facepalm.gif]
[image: facepalm2.gif]

As the comment in the code says, I've renamed them to `facepalm.gif` and `facepalm2.gif`.

I've created a macro `\makegraphic` that takes as an argument the base name (in this case `facepalm` or `facepalm2`). The first thing it tries to do is to count the number of `.png` files by opening them one at a time until one fails to open. If it turns out that none of them exist, then it executes `\explodegif` to call `convert`. It tries a second time to count the number of `.png` files. If this fails, TeX stops. (I could have used a real error message, but this is just for demonstration so an undefined control sequence works just fine.)

Converting the `.gif` is done by executing one of the internal `bashful` macros. The reason for this is `\bash` mucks about with character codes and eventually looks for `^^M#1^^M\END` where `^^M` is active. Initially, I did similar tricks in order to make `\bash` work, but in the end, `\bashIV{shell commands here}` was just easier to do. Note that I needed to make `%` a normal symbols character so I made `^^A` a comment for use in the macro.

In the end, the result is what you want. They are animated although, obviously, my screenshot is not.

[image]

Comment: @TH: +1 for the solution and if I could, +100 for using the images Jean Luc Picard ;-)

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 I'm using TeX Live 2017 on macOS.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영: I have not use this code by TH's (yet), but I do trust his/her expertise that the result of the code is what he posted

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 (I'm away from a computer so I can't do much right now, but did you run `pdflatex -shell-escape foo.tex` twice? On the first run, it should execute `convert` and produce the .pdfs. Does this happen? The second run is necessary according to the animate documentation. Are the gifs in the same directory as the .tex?

Comment: (+1) But I don't see why you needed to do anything to get `\bash` to work. It just seemed to work for me. Then the `%` etc. all works without messing around.

Comment: Because I needed a literal % in the replacement text of a macro. Maybe there's a better way?

Comment: Oops. I meant to tag @cfr.

Comment: I just used the `%` normally. The backslash in my code is just because the shell will interpret it otherwise, rather than `find`.

Comment: `$i.gif` should be quoted in a shell script, unless the script is responsible for the name. But it is not really worth worrying about here.

Comment: @TH. I confirm that this approach works after `pdflatex -shell-escape code.tex`. Why `-shell-espace` has to be used?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 it's needed for bashful to work. It would be quite dangerous if compiling a document could execute arbitrary code by default.

Answer (score 5):

**This is an answer to the current version of the question.**

> *Note that I do not see the attraction of this and do not recommend it.*
>
> ## *Caveat emptor*

Configuration for testing purposes:

- A `.tex` file with content specified below in the working directory.
- A sub-directory `anim`.
- Three animated GIFs for conversion: `anim/horn.gif`, `anim/horna.gif` and `anim/hornb.gif`. All animations are the work of  Danjiro Daiwa and can be found at https://codepen.io/danjiro/post/how-to-make-animated-gif-from-openclipart. To compile the example, download [this animation](https://qiita-image-store.s3.amazonaws.com/0/67734/d987e21c-0666-0f1a-9298-9264ac038e7d.gif), name it `horn.gif` and then make two copies, `horna.gif` and `hornb.gif`. (You can actually name them what you want as long as they have the extension `.gif`, but to duplicate what I did, name as specified.)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{bashful,animate,pgffor}
\begin{document}
\bash
find ./anim -name '*.gif' -execdir bash -c 'for i;
  do
   c=$(convert -coalesce -identify "$i" "${i/\.gif/.png}" | wc -l);
   ((c--));
   printf \%b "$(basename ${i/\.gif/})/$c,";
  done' bash {} + | sed 's/,$//'
\END
\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \foreach \i/\j in \bashStdout {\animategraphics[width=.2\linewidth,controls,autoplay,loop]{12}{anim/\i-}{0}{\j} \\ }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3 animated horns]

To adapt the code for another environment, edit to alter the `./anim` appropriately in the `find` statement and the `anim` appropriately in the `\animategraphics` argument.

Note that my PDF viewer cannot actually run animations, so I cannot tell for sure if this works or not. I would be grateful if somebody could enlighten me.

---

As I say, I have no idea what the point of this is. How often are you going to want multiple animations in a single slide in some way you can manage using a loop? If you really have multiple animations in slides, you are just creating visual distractions for your audience.

But, this site is not about good ideas, but only the implementation of whatever ideas people happen to have, however misguided they may be. Otherwise, this answer would not exist.

> **Warning!** Do not try this at home. Not recommended with or without parental guidance, but if you must do it, consider sparing your parents the heartache.

---

## EDIT

Here's a version for use in the same directory.

Setup: working directory contains

```
horn.gif horna.gif hornb.gif test2.tex
```

`test2.tex`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{bashful,animate,pgffor}
\begin{document}
\bash
find . -name '*.gif' -execdir bash -c 'for i;
  do
   c=$(convert -coalesce -identify "$i" "${i/\.gif/.png}" | wc -l);
   ((c--));
   printf \%b "$(basename ${i/\.gif/})/$c,";
  done' bash {} + | sed 's/,$//'
\END
\begin{frame}
  \centering
  \foreach \i/\j in \bashStdout {\animategraphics[width=.2\linewidth,controls,autoplay,loop]{12}{\i-}{0}{\j} \\ }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

`test2.sh` should contain:

```
% find . -name '*.gif' -execdir bash -c 'for i;
  do
   c=$(convert -coalesce -identify "$i" "${i/\.gif/.png}" | wc -l);
   ((c--));
   printf \%b "$(basename ${i/\.gif/})/$c,";
  done' bash {} + | sed 's/,$//'
```

`test2.stdout` should contain (with no newline at the end):

```
horna/9,hornb/9,horn/9
```

`test2.stderr` should be empty.

`test2.log` should include:

```
\openout5 = `test2.sh'.

runsystem(bash -c "bash test2.sh >test2.stdout 2>test2.stderr || echo $? >test2
.exitCode")...executed.

\openout5 = `test2.sh'.


after EOF
<horna-0.png, id=24, 321.2pt x 321.2pt>
File: horna-0.png Graphic file (type png)
<use horna-0.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: horna-0.png  used on input line 15. on input line 15.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 321.19922pt x 321.19922pt on input lin
e 15.
 <./horna-0.png> <a0,fr0>
<horna-1.png, id=33, 321.2pt x 321.2pt>
File: horna-1.png Graphic file (type png)
<use horna-1.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: horna-1.png  used on input line 15. on input line 15.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 321.19922pt x 321.19922pt on input lin
e 15.
 <./horna-1.png> <a0,fr1>
<horna-2.png, id=42, 321.2pt x 321.2pt>
File: horna-2.png Graphic file (type png)
<use horna-2.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: horna-2.png  used on input line 15. on input line 15.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 321.19922pt x 321.19922pt on input lin
e 15.
 <./horna-2.png> <a0,fr2>
<horna-3.png, id=51, 321.2pt x 321.2pt>
File: horna-3.png Graphic file (type png)
<use horna-3.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: horna-3.png  used on input line 15. on input line 15.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 321.19922pt x 321.19922pt on input lin
e 15.
 <./horna-3.png> <a0,fr3>
<horna-4.png, id=60, 321.2pt x 321.2pt>
File: horna-4.png Graphic file (type png)
<use horna-4.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: horna-4.png  used on input line 15. on input line 15.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 321.19922pt x 321.19922pt on input lin
e 15.
 <./horna-4.png> <a0,fr4>
<horna-5.png, id=69, 321.2pt x 321.2pt>
File: horna-5.png Graphic file (type png)
<use horna-5.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: horna-5.png  used on input line 15. on input line 15.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 321.19922pt x 321.19922pt on input lin
e 15.
 <./horna-5.png> <a0,fr5>
<a0,fr6> <a0,fr7> <a0,fr8> <a0,fr9>
<hornb-0.png, id=108, 321.2pt x 321.2pt>
File: hornb-0.png Graphic file (type png)
<use hornb-0.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: hornb-0.png  used on input line 15. on input line 15.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 321.19922pt x 321.19922pt on input lin
e 15.
 <./hornb-0.png> <a1,fr0>
<hornb-1.png, id=117, 321.2pt x 321.2pt>
File: hornb-1.png Graphic file (type png)
<use hornb-1.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: hornb-1.png  used on input line 15. on input line 15.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 321.19922pt x 321.19922pt on input lin
e 15.
 <./hornb-1.png>
<a1,fr1>
<hornb-2.png, id=126, 321.2pt x 321.2pt>
File: hornb-2.png Graphic file (type png)
<use hornb-2.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: hornb-2.png  used on input line 15. on input line 15.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 321.19922pt x 321.19922pt on input lin
e 15.
 <./hornb-2.png> <a1,fr2>
<hornb-3.png, id=135, 321.2pt x 321.2pt>
File: hornb-3.png Graphic file (type png)
<use hornb-3.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: hornb-3.png  used on input line 15. on input line 15.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 321.19922pt x 321.19922pt on input lin
e 15.
 <./hornb-3.png> <a1,fr3>
<hornb-4.png, id=144, 321.2pt x 321.2pt>
File: hornb-4.png Graphic file (type png)
<use hornb-4.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: hornb-4.png  used on input line 15. on input line 15.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 321.19922pt x 321.19922pt on input lin
e 15.
 <./hornb-4.png>
<a1,fr4>
<hornb-5.png, id=153, 321.2pt x 321.2pt>
File: hornb-5.png Graphic file (type png)
<use hornb-5.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: hornb-5.png  used on input line 15. on input line 15.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 321.19922pt x 321.19922pt on input lin
e 15.
 <./hornb-5.png> <a1,fr5> <a1,fr6> <a1,fr7> <a1,fr8> <a1,fr9>
<horn-0.png, id=191, 321.2pt x 321.2pt>
File: horn-0.png Graphic file (type png)
<use horn-0.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: horn-0.png  used on input line 15. on input line 15.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 321.19922pt x 321.19922pt on input lin
e 15.
 <./horn-0.png> <a2,fr0>
<horn-1.png, id=200, 321.2pt x 321.2pt>
File: horn-1.png Graphic file (type png)
<use horn-1.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: horn-1.png  used on input line 15. on input line 15.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 321.19922pt x 321.19922pt on input lin
e 15.
 <./horn-1.png> <a2,fr1>
<horn-2.png, id=209, 321.2pt x 321.2pt>
File: horn-2.png Graphic file (type png)
<use horn-2.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: horn-2.png  used on input line 15. on input line 15.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 321.19922pt x 321.19922pt on input lin
e 15.
 <./horn-2.png> <a2,fr2>
<horn-3.png, id=218, 321.2pt x 321.2pt>
File: horn-3.png Graphic file (type png)
<use horn-3.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: horn-3.png  used on input line 15. on input line 15.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 321.19922pt x 321.19922pt on input lin
e 15.
 <./horn-3.png>
<a2,fr3>
<horn-4.png, id=227, 321.2pt x 321.2pt>
File: horn-4.png Graphic file (type png)
<use horn-4.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: horn-4.png  used on input line 15. on input line 15.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 321.19922pt x 321.19922pt on input lin
e 15.
 <./horn-4.png> <a2,fr4>
<horn-5.png, id=236, 321.2pt x 321.2pt>
File: horn-5.png Graphic file (type png)
<use horn-5.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: horn-5.png  used on input line 15. on input line 15.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 321.19922pt x 321.19922pt on input lin
e 15.
 <./horn-5.png> <a2,fr5> <a2,fr6> <a2,fr7>
<a2,fr8> <a2,fr9>
```

**EDIT EDIT** Specify `bash` rather than `sh` in case `sh` is something else.

Comment: My code seems a bit short in comparison with the question, let alone the other answer. Did I miss something out? Worried because I can't actually test the animation part.

Comment: I can't test now but it looks reasonable. The only real difference is yours runs convert on every invocation of pdflatex.

Comment: I probably should have mentioned it in my answer, but my goal was to minimize the use of bash since that's something that should be done separately from compiling the document. And just including gifs in whatever order `find` returns (locale-dependent?) seems like a bad plan. So the key idea was simply enumerating the files with a known pattern which isn't too hard.

Comment: @TH. I figure if you care about efficiency, you don't use LaTeX to run `convert` in a `bash` shell.  As I say, I can't imagine why one would want to do this with multiple animations at one go anyway. My aim in this answer was to maximise the use of `bash` so that as much as possible was pushed onto the shell ;). This does have some advantages. Once you are invoking a shell, using it is much faster than using TeX to count, for example, because you can just get the information from `convert` and use `bash` to adjust the count. But really, I wouldn't use either your code or mine for anything :-).

Comment: I agree with all of that. :)

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Did you set up the test environment as directed? To run the example, you need a sub-directory `anim` containing one or more GIFs. To get my output, it should contain `horn.gif`, `horna.gif` and `hornb.gif`. Or you can adapt the code to use a directory other than `anim`, of course.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 `test2.tex` should be in the directory which contains `anim`. `anim` is a sub-directory. If you want everything in the same directory, you can just use `.` rather than `./anim` in `find` and remove `anim/` from `\animategraphics`. ***But to run the code as given, you must set the directories up as specified.***

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Or you can, of course, specify absolute paths if you prefer. But then you need to specify them rather than using the relative pathnames I gave in the example. (Obviously, absolute paths on my system would not work on yours, so I used relative paths in the example.) But, since you got T.H.'s code working, don't you have a satisfactory solution already anyway?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 I posted a version based on your set up i.e. everything in the working directory, file named `test2.tex` and included results from various generated files for you to compare. Beyond that, make sure you clear all generated files before recompiling and then check versions against vanilla TeX Live 2017. But, if you have a working version from T.H., my version doesn't matter whether it works for you or not, does it? I don't understand why you want this to work if you've got code which does what you want. It works fine for me, but if not for you, why not just use what does?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 Try changing `sh` to `bash`. Apparently, `sh` differs on your system.

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 I've altered the code throughout the post to specify this now.

Comment: @cfr I confirm that your current code works also in my system! The problem was in `sh`, it works with `bash`. Do you understand why it can be like that?

Comment: @LéoLéopoldHertz준영 The `((c--))` is `bash` syntax. On my system, `sh` is a symbolic link to `bash` (although it makes a difference which name is used to invoke it, I think). Once I saw the standard error you posted, I realised this could not be the case on your system. (It couldn't be a version issue: `((c--))` is not at all some recently introduced feature - it is just standard and has been for years.) I figured using `bash` instead of `sh` was, therefore, the simplest solution. `sh` used to be distinct in my distro, too, but I guess it still is in yours.

Answer (score 2):

[Originally a comment, but got ridiculous.]

**Note that this answer addressed the question in its original form.** I leave it here as it still attempts to explain why the OP's code is confused. However, it does not offer a positive suggestion, as that wasn't possible at the time.

---

What does this do?

```
\bash[stdoutFile=gif_series.tex]

    % AlexG, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373780/13173
        \animategraphics[
          width=\textwidth,
          controls,autoplay,loop
        ]{12}{out000}{00}{16} % TODO here {out000}{00}{16} for dynamics

    \END
```

`\bash[stdoutFile=gif_series.tex]` tells LaTeX to use bash to execute the script to follow, directing 'standard out' to the file `gif_series.tex`. This is any output the script would normally send to the terminal as output, as opposed to errors and so on. So, you'll get a new file `gif_series.tex` (if it doesn't already exist) with the non-error result of the script, if any.

```
    % AlexG, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373780/13173
```

bash won't know what to do with this. It isn't bash code. In LaTeX, it would be a comment, but bash will just give an error.

```
        \animategraphics[
          width=\textwidth,
          controls,autoplay,loop
        ]{12}{out000}{00}{16} % TODO here {out000}{00}{16} for dynamics
```

Might do something in LaTeX, but won't do anything in bash except give you errors.

The LaTeX stuff cannot be part of the script. If you want to split the GIF as part of the compilation, you can do so by having bash do that. You can also write the file list to a file and then input it back to LaTeX. Or you can save it to a variable and recover the value, if you have a relatively small file list. But you ***cannot*** do what you want in one step because bash is not LaTeX and LaTeX is not bash.

[You can use `\splice`, but then special characters are going to be difficult and it looks as if you need those here, even if it is not entirely clear what you are trying to do.]

Comment: Please, see the pseudocode, I made it clearer. The idea is to find the max iteration count of each image set. Apply this info to AlexG code foreach image type.