# How to have dot separator in animategraphics filename?

Tags: animate

I really like to use dot separator as an universal separator, also in filenames, now trying to find a way to use it with `animate` package. 
Code where the filename `gait.ataxia` fails but also surrounding it with curly brackets fails: `{gait.ataxia}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
        %https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/373780/13173
        % TODO fails here
        \animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop]{2}{gait.ataxia}{00}{16}
    \end{figure}            
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output: `! Package animate Error: None of the files`

Output with surrounding extra curly brackets: `! Argument of \end has an extra }.`

### Testing AlexG's proposal

Adding `\usepackage{grffile}`, clear the errors but the animation itself is full-stop where action links do not respond. 
Without *filename.dot* structure, the animation works normally.

Output: animation in full-stop + animation link actions do not respond

OS: Debian 8.7
TeXLive: 2017
PDF viewer: `acroread` Adobe Acrobat 9.5.x
Gif image source: [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/373379/13173) in Fig. 1 with the corresponding `convert` command run

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add

```
\usepackage{grffile}
```

.

Comment: Hm. Works out for me. I will put together an example on ShareLaTeX.

Comment: Well, on [**ShareLaTeX**](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/594267858920e4376fb7e7fd) it works even without `grffile`.

Comment: I am using TeXLive-2017 too (with packages updated this morning).  `grffile` does the trick.

Comment: Works now on my system too with/without `grffile` after TeXLive 2017 package updates! How is `grffile` necessary here? Can it improve the stability? I want to understand why the code did not work in my earlier system state.

Comment: I seem to use a different mirror site for TL updates. I test without `grffile` tomorrow.

Comment: No change, `grffile` still needed.

Comment: What is your output without `grffile`?

Comment: No output file. It does not compile. `! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .file00000.png.`